# How to fix socket.io-java-client not work properly in fabric mods

Tags: java, gradle, minecraft-fabric, socket.io-java-client

I'm trying to use websocket.io-client java for my minecraft fabric mods so i added this code in my build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    // other implementation
    implementation 'org.json:json:20211205'
    implementation ('io.socket:engine.io-client:2.1.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    // Socket IO
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

and its work well in my IDE. But after i built the mod and add it into my launcher, it crashed for

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute entrypoint stage 'main' due to errors, provided by 'cloudchat'!
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.lambda$invoke0$0(EntrypointUtils.java:51)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.util.ExceptionUtil.gatherExceptions(ExceptionUtil.java:33)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:49)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke(EntrypointUtils.java:35)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.Hooks.startClient(Hooks.java:52)
    at net.minecraft.class_310.<init>(class_310.java:468)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:198)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:462)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:23)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launchWithMainClass(OneSixLauncher.java:210)
    at org.multimc.onesix.OneSixLauncher.launch(OneSixLauncher.java:245)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.listen(EntryPoint.java:143)
    at org.multimc.EntryPoint.main(EntryPoint.java:34)
    Suppressed: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.RuntimeException: Mixin transformation of net.minecraft.class_634 failed
        at de.keksuccino.fancymenu.networking.Packets.registerAll(Packets.java:25)
        at de.keksuccino.fancymenu.FancyMenu.onInitialize(FancyMenu.java:154)
        at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:47)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Mixin transformation of net.minecraft.class_634 failed
        at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.getPostMixinClassByteArray(KnotClassDelegate.java:427)
        at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.tryLoadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:323)
        at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.loadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:218)
        at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:112)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 18 more
    Caused by: org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.throwables.MixinTransformerError: An unexpected critical error was encountered
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinProcessor.applyMixins(MixinProcessor.java:392)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClass(MixinTransformer.java:234)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinTransformer.transformClassBytes(MixinTransformer.java:202)
        at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.getPostMixinClassByteArray(KnotClassDelegate.java:422)
        ... 22 more
    Caused by: org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.throwables.MixinPreProcessorException: Attach error for CloudChat.mixins.json:ChatMixin from mod cloudchat during activity: [Transform -> Method onSendChatMessage(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/spongepowered/asm/mixin/injection/callback/CallbackInfo;)V -> INVOKEVIRTUAL -> io/socket/client/Socket::disconnect:()Lio/socket/client/Socket;]
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.attach(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:313)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.createContextFor(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:277)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinInfo.createContextFor(MixinInfo.java:1289)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinApplicatorStandard.apply(MixinApplicatorStandard.java:294)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.TargetClassContext.apply(TargetClassContext.java:421)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.TargetClassContext.applyMixins(TargetClassContext.java:403)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinProcessor.applyMixins(MixinProcessor.java:363)
        ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.socket.client.Socket
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.transformMemberReference(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:786)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.transformMethod(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:772)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.transform(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:738)
        at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinPreProcessorStandard.attach(MixinPreProcessorStandard.java:307)
        ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.socket.client.Socket
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/socket/client/IO
    at dev.dinofeng.cloudchat.socket.SocketConnection.connect(SocketConnection.java:18)
    at dev.dinofeng.cloudchat.socket.SocketConnection.<init>(SocketConnection.java:14)
    at dev.dinofeng.cloudchat.CloudChat.initClient(CloudChat.java:44)
    at dev.dinofeng.cloudchat.CloudChatInitializer.onInitialize(CloudChatInitializer.java:16)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.entrypoint.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:47)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.socket.client.IO
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassDelegate.loadClass(KnotClassDelegate.java:226)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotClassLoader.loadClass(KnotClassLoader.java:112)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 20 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I had tried to download the source and put it into src/main/java but seems not working.
How to fix it?

Comment: Java can't find io.socket.client.IO because it's not installed anywhere in your mod or in Minecraft apparently